# Which browsers support triggering click event on input[type="file"] elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications,

> Starting in Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4 / Thunderbird 3.3 / SeaMonkey 2.1) ,
>   you can hide the admittedly ugly file  element and present your
>   own interface for opening the file picker and displaying which file or
>   files the user has selected.

With something like this (using jQuery):

```
$('a.upload').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('input[type="file"]').click();
});
```

I am not asking what other ways there are to do this better. I am wondering what other browsers support the click event for input file just like this?

Comment: Chrome does. FF 3.5 does not. IE obviously does not (may be IE9 and up do, but haven't tested).

Comment: I just confirmed that it works in:  IE8 and IE9

Answer (score 1):

firefox 3.2+ versions do not support AFAIK because there is some security issue if the file input is hidden, chrome and ie support that I guess
that's why people trigger the click putting the file input directly behind the fake elements

Comment: Firefox 17 *does* support .click() . I have no idea in what version it changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've run a test that hides the original file input with display: none and uses jQuery to run the click event on a trigger button.

Works in at least: IE7 and later, FF 4.0 and later, Safari 4.0 and later (Win), Chrome 14.0 and later.
Does *not* work in: FF 3.6 and earlier.